# Solidity: Is there a good way to initialise a struct in an array?

Tags: solidity

I was wondering what is the best practice for initializing a struct which is a member of an Array?

I want to fill my smart contract with some information upon initializing it. That I intend to mainly store in an array, so it is stored in a coherent way when later adding more information.

I am currently doing it in a similar matter as below. It can get a bit messy though and was looking for a better way.

```
contract ExampleContract {

struct ExampleStruct {
    address owner,
    string text
}

ExampleStruct[] public exampleStructs;

function ExampleContract( address myAddress, string myText ) {
    ExampleStruct memory es;

    es.owner = myAddress;
    es.text = myText;

    exampleStructs.push(es);
}

...

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just going to put it in storage anyway, there's no reason to declare a memory struct. Just do:

```
contract ExampleContract {

struct ExampleStruct {
    address owner;
    string text;
}

ExampleStruct[] public exampleStructs;

function ExampleContract( address myAddress, string myText ) {
    exampleStructs.push(ExampleStruct(myAddress, myText));
}

...

}
```

Comment: What if `ExampleStruct` had a parameter `uint[] x`. How would I modify `exampleStructs.push(ExampleStruct(myAddress, myText)` to also initialize x to an empty array?